# Sed. Удалить строку содержащуую и символ % и символ #

Tags: sed

Есть файл test.txt с содержанием

```
text1
text2
%#
text3#text4%text5
text6%text7#text8
%
%%%%%
#
#####
```

Хочу удалить строки которые содержат в себе **и** символ % **и** символ #
Чтоб вывод был такой:

```
text1
text2
%
%%%%%
#
#####
```

Пришел пока к такому `sed '/%/d; /#/d' test.txt`
Но оно удаляет строки которые сожержат **или** % **или** # и вывод получается такой

```
text1
text2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sh
$ sed -e '/#.*%\|%.*#/d' ./file.txt
```

Comment: Точно? Что-то меня смущает комбинация `-e` и `\|`.

Comment: @Qwertiy `-e` — всего лишь начало программы, которое я всегда указываю для ясности, а `\|` используется вместо второго `-e` для краткости, да и команда так яснее, как мне кажется.

Comment: Хм.. Кажется я перепутал `-e` и `-r`?

Comment: `-r` — *GNU*'изм, я их стараюсь избегать.